# Cannot autowire service in symfony

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to split one big service.yaml to few smaller files. In origin service.yaml I had

services:

```
_defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: false

App\Domain\Country\Infrastructure\Repository\CountryRepository:
    public: true
    class: App\Domain\Country\Infrastructure\Repository\CountryRepository
    factory: ["@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager", getRepository]
    arguments: [App\Domain\Country\Entity\Country]
```

Then I added import at the begining service.yam

```
imports:
  - {resource: services/repositories.yaml}
```

repositories.yaml

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: true

     App\Domain\Country\Infrastructure\Repository\CountryRepository:
        factory: ["@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager", getRepository]
        arguments: [App\Domain\Country\Entity\Country]
```

After that I started to get error

```
  Cannot autowire service "App\Domain\Country\Infrastructure\Repository\Count  
  ryRepository": argument "$class" of method "Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::  
  __construct()" references class "Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata" but no  
   such service exists.
```

What's wrong there?

- https://pastebin.com/Uy85YJmc (service.yaml)
- https://pastebin.com/ZesAw3sD (repositories.yaml)

Comment: remove `_defaults` from `repositories/yaml`. Also indent `App\Domain\Country\Infrastructure\Repository\CountryRepository`

Comment: thanks, but the same :(

Comment: Edit your question and put new files

Comment: I've added a links on pastebin

Comment: Symfony version ?

Comment: the latest. symfony 4

Comment: If you are using autowiring, do you even need to provide a definition for the repo? Just having it as a constructor argument should be enough... Just make sure that your Country entity has the repository annotation for the CountryRepository class

Comment: because I'm using one third party library where I sent container directly for such queries. Probably is it possible to do by other way?

$repository = $this->container->get('App\Domain\Billing\Counterparty\Infrastructure\Repository\CounterpartyRepository');
return $repository->getById($input);

Comment: You should avoid sending the whole container into anything. But that would probably work. At some point you may hit recursive issues especially if you start using the request etc... I would look to avoid sending the whole container to whatever class.

Comment: Yes, I know this is a bad practice :( But I have no idea how to wrap third party library for support DI

Comment: Inject the 3rd party lib into a service along with any other dependencies and use it in isolation, rather than trying to wire it from the outside

Comment: let me check, but it's not fast

Comment: @akor - all yaml files under config/services.yaml are automatically loaded by Kernel.php so there is no need for an explicit import.  The error message is not coming from your configuration.  Rather, you have something else that is scanning your Infrastructure directory and attempting to create a service out of everything it finds.  Check the rest of your autowire setup and figure out how to exclude the directory.  Or do as others have suggested and just extend the ServiceEntityRepository.

Comment: @akor did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to define the repository for the purposes of autowiring.

services.yaml:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

Entity\Country:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CountryRepository")
 */
class Country
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Repository\CountryRepository:

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Country;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;

/**
 * @method Country|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method Country|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method Country[]    findAll()
 * @method Country[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class CountryRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Country::class);
    }
}
```

And finally, your service:

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use App\Repository\CountryRepository;

class ExampleService
{
    /**
     * @var CountryRepository
     */
    private $repository;

    /**
     * @param CountryRepository $repository
     */
    public function __construct(CountryRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }
}
```

The autowiring will see that you've injected that `CountryRepository` into the `ExampleService` constructor and handle the rest.

Comment: I'll try your version a little later. But correct me, will it work with $repository = $this->container->get('App\Domain\Billing\Counterparty\Infrastructure\Repository\CounterpartyRepository'); ? How to get repository from container in that case?

Comment: That should work (or prefix with @ and use in the service definition), but as mentioned, sounds smelly because the container is being injected. Difficult to advise without knowing the exact problem but you should be able to configure your third party library and pass the things you need it to have rather than doing that.

Answer (score -1):

Use named arguments instead :

**repositories.yaml**

```
services:

     App\Domain\Country\Infrastructure\Repository\CountryRepository:
        factory: ["@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager", getRepository]
        arguments:
            $class: '@App\Domain\Country\Entity\Country'
```

Comment: Inside repositories.yaml.  When I have all repository declarations in services.yaml it works fine. But once I split it I get errror.

Comment: try moving `imports` at very top line above the parameters